# Free-Fall of a Body in a Non-Uniform Gravitational Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

What is the free-fall time of a test mass on a mass $M$ from height $2R$ to $R$?

My Solution

---

The equation of motion of the test mass is
$$\Delta{R}=-gt\Delta{t}$$
which on integration gives
$$R={1\over2}gt^2$$
Then free-fall time
$$\tau=\sqrt{2R\over g}$$
But acceleration due to gravity of a body of radius $R$ is
$$g=\frac{GM}{R^2}$$
Therefore the free-fall time is
$$\tau=\sqrt{2R^3\over GM}$$

However, since I don't know the radius of the mass $M$ , I'm using the expression
$$\tau=\sqrt{y_0^3\over GM}\times\left[\sqrt{{y\over y_0}{\left(1-{y\over y_0}\right)}}+\cos^{-1}\sqrt{y\over y_0}\right]$$
With
$y_0=2R,$ and $y=R$
the free-fall time I thus obtain is
$$\tau=\left({{2\pi\over 3} +1}\right)\sqrt{R^3\over GM}$$

It does not feel right!

Comment: It does not feel right because you consider constant gravity twice in the first two equations. And you shouldn't. The answer is quite more complicated, see [Free fall in non-uniform field](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252773/).

Comment: In the question, is $R$ supposed to be the radius of a spherical body (?) with mass $M$? Generally the gravitational force and therefore the acceleration due to gravity depends on the distance between the bodies, so is not constant during the fall. If the distance through which it falls is sufficiently small you can approximate gravity with a constant acceleration as we often do using $g=GM/R^2$ since we are usually concerned with free fall distances much smaller than the earth radius.  However if you really have a long fall like in your question you cannot use this approximation.

Comment: There is this beautiful argument by @StanLiou http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184377/ which gives me another expression $$\tau=\pi\sqrt{\left(2R^3\over GM\right)}$$

Comment: @SayontönVöttacharjo That is not the StanLiou's answer for the problem you proposed. The answer he gave is in terms of the undetermined parameter $\eta$ and it coincides with the answer given in link I posted. What you wrote is the particular case of a full straight line orbit around point mass.

Comment: The free-fall time computed from your equation @Diracology 

$$t=\sqrt{\frac{mx_i^2}{2K}}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x_i}}}+\frac 12 \sin\left(2\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x_i}}}\right)\right].$$
gives me 
$$\tau=\sqrt{2R^2\over GM}\left[{\pi\over 3} + {1\over 4}\right]$$

However, following StanLiou's argument, which he applied for the same problem, I obtain 
$$\tau=\pi\sqrt{2R^3\over GM}$$

So, how can you say that the orbit is a straight line ?

Comment: $\sqrt{R^2/GM}$ by the way is units of seconds/(meters)^.5, which is not units of time. It should along the lines of $\sqrt{R^3/GM}$

Comment: Josh and Sayonton, thank you for pointing these out. The correct expression is $$t=\sqrt{\frac{mx_i^3}{2K}}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x_i}}}-\frac 12 \sin\left(2\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x_i}}}\right)\right].$$ Then compute the time to fall to the center and multiply it by four (full orbit). That gives the same result obtained by StanLiou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you pose is actually much harder than you probably originally thought. The reason is you are trying to find the time elapsed in a time-varying gravitational field, remember the test mass (mass $m$) is not undergoing a constant acceleration, but it is varying, since $g = \frac{GM}{r^2}$ and $r$ is of course changing. However, you can still solve this problem. Since the gravitational force is conservative, we can apply the conservation of energy:
$$\frac{1}{2} m v_f^2 -\frac{GMm}{r_f} = \frac{1}{2} m v_0 ^2 - \frac{GMm}{r_0}.$$ This is just the sum of the kinetic and potential energies initially and finally. Assume that the test mass (mass $m$) starts from rest, so that $v_0 = 0$, and our equation simplifies to 
$$ v_f^2 = 2GM\Big(\frac{1}{r_f}-\frac{1}{r_0}\Big).$$ 
Ok that is some progress but what we want is the *time*, not the velocity! Note however the definition of the velocity, which is $v \equiv \frac{dr}{dt}$, just the derivative of the position, so we get $$ \frac{dr}{dt} = \pm \sqrt{2GM \Big(\frac{1}{r_f}-\frac{1}{r_0}\Big)},$$
where I have taken the square root of both sides. Now you can notice, all we have to do is perform an integral to find the *total* time $\tau$ as you call it, but we need an integral variable, so instead of writing $r_f$, we write $r$ since we are **integrating** from our initial $r_0 = 2R$ to our final $r_f = R$. Ok, inverting the equation, we get 
$$\frac{dt}{dr} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2GM}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r_0}}}$$ By the way, I'm going to define $\mu \equiv GM$, which is something called the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter), for convenience (and mainly because I am lazy and don't want to write it all the time). Keeping only the minus sign (so that the total time $\tau$ remains positive as you will see), we get the following integral:
\begin{align}
\tau &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu}}\int_{r_0}^{r_f} \frac{dr}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r_0}}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu}}\int_{2R}^{R} \frac{dr}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{2R}}}.
\end{align}
The rest of the problem is just performing this integration, which I will leave up to you. I hope this clarifies everything!

Comment: I'm tying to solve the same problem. WolframAlpha integrates your expression to include imaginary terms -- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt(1%2Fr-1%2FR)+dr -- are you sure you've gotten this right?